# Python implementation of the Sequitur algorithm?

Tags: compression, sequences

I need to use the Sequitur algorithm for a bioinformatics project but so far I haven't found any Python implementations of the algorithm. This is what I've got so far:

```
    def new_rule(sequence,rules,x,y,z):
    y = list(y)
    if max(y) > 1:
        ind = y.index(max(y))

        locations = np.zeros(max(y))

        counter = 0
        for i, j in enumerate(z):
            if j == x[ind]:
                locations[counter] = i
                counter+=1

    new_rule = 'A'+str(len(rules)+1)
    rules.append([new_rule,x[ind]])

    return sequence.replace(x[ind],new_rule), rules

def word_count(sequence):
    return len(sequence)-sequence.count(' ')

def recursive_sequitur(sequence,rules):
    count_down = word_count(sequence)-1

x,y,z = n_grams(sequence,count_down)

while count_down>1:
    if len(y) > 1 and max(y) > 1:
        sequence, rules = new_rule(sequence,rules,x,y,z)
        x,y,z = n_grams(sequence,count_down)

    else:
        count_down-=1
        x,y,z = n_grams(sequence,count_down)

return sequence, rules
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Parallel Sequitur](https://github.com/raysaagar/parallel-sequitur) for Python?

> We implemented serial and parallel versions of the Sequitur
>   compression algorithm. The Sequitur algorithm uses hierarchical
>   structure and sequences of discrete symbols to compress files by
>   exploiting repetative structures found in strings.

[concat_parallel.py](https://github.com/raysaagar/parallel-sequitur/blob/master/parallel/concat_parallel.py): simple parallel implementation of the Sequitur algorithm. Text is split among workers which run a version of the serial algorithm before the main process merges all results in order.